# PyQt5 QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make Pushbutton show me the text like this
1 You clicked
2 PushButton
not in the same line.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

Class Ui_MainWindow (object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
        MainWindow.resize(506, 312) 
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        
        # adding pushbutton 
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 150, 93, 28)) 

        # adding signal and slot 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.changelabeltext) 
    
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget) 
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 221, 20))   

        # keeping the text of label empty before button get clicked 
        self.label.setText("")   
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow) 
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow) 

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate 
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow")) 
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Push Button")) 
        
    def changelabeltext(self): 

        # changing the text of label after button get clicked 
        self.label.setText("You clicked PushButton")     

        # Hiding pushbutton from the main window 
        # after button get clicked. 
        self.pushButton.hide() 

If __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication (sys.argv)
    
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() 
    ui = Ui_MainWindow() 
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow) 
    MainWindow.show() 

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ali, can you be more specific about the formatting of the text/button, what is currently wrong with it? They are not on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you technically only asked how to place "You clicked" below "Pushbutton" (which can be done by putting a newline in the string `"You clicked \nPushButton"`), when you do this you will run into another fundamental problem with your code, mainly that you are positioning widgets by drawing them inside a `QRect` with a static position.

This will produce problems when you change the text or window size, since you will have to manually change the coordinates of the `QRect` to place then in the correct position.

I took the liberty of rewriting your `setupUi` to use layouts (which I recommend you research) instead of `QRect`'s. Hope this helps, it should be a drop in replacement:

```py
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
        MainWindow.resize(506, 312) 
        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.changelabeltext) 
    
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.label.setText("")   

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)

        self.hbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget) 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow) 
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Comment: Do note that, while the objection about using fixed geometries is correct, the label can be properly updated to show the full contents by calling [`adjustSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize).

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, you want the text to be displayed as follows:
`You clicked`
`PushButton`
To achieve this, try placing a newline character in between the words like this:
`"You clicked \nPushButton"`

Alternatively, if this does not display correctly, try adding a new label with the second half of the text to it, or increase the size of the rectangle in which you placed the text.

Comment: Although this does put the "Pushbutton" text on a newline, because he placed the text inside a `QRect` with a static size most of the text will be cut off